# How to replay missed Pusher events

Tags: webhooks, pusher

I have the following model.

[image]

Events are published by my back-end services. Webhooks are processed by a web-app that simply queues jobs based on the event that is fired. The queueing service subsequently can do things such as make calls to other back-end services. The issue with this model is that events that are missed, e.g when the webhook processor app experiences downtime, are lost. What are best practices for tracking and replaying these missed events?

I know to avoid the anti-pattern [database as a queue](https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-11-23-why-is-a-database-not-the-right-tool-for-a-queue-based-system.html), and it seems like the solution would involve some kind of message queue. Hoping that someone that has solved this problem could shed some light.

Comment: I assume you've already seen the documentation on Pusher's webhook [retry strategy](https://docs.pusher.com/chatkit/webhooks#retry-strategy). Basically you will need to design a reliable, durable subsystem for your Webhook Processor. Typical approaches include pooled workers, serverless functions, etc. Unfortunately your question is rather broad and open to opinion, but wanted to at least give you some feedback.

Comment: @dmulter thanks for the feedback! I am looking for a solution for longer outages, but retries are certainly useful for short connectivity issues. I thought maybe the solution I'm looking for is a common problem. Do you know of any patterns or solutions that exist already?

Comment: I’m easy to find online @dmulter where I can share more about a solution that might help.